# Order bars by calculated means

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm trying to order bars by using geom_bar(). The problem is, that I first compute the mean by

```
+ stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", fill = "White", colour = "Black")
```

so I can't order the values by vector, cause the values doesn't exist as a column.
I get bars with different means and now I wnat to order them by there mean-value. R orders them alphabeticly.
So I got this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oaegj.png)

But I want to order them by their y-axis values, so the biggest (or switched by the lowest) bar comes at first, then the second....

At last, I need to flip axis by using

```
 last_plot() + coord_flip()
```

so I can read the names horizontal and be able to change text-size if I wish - without overlapping.
But I also want the bars sorted by their means. Now I get this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfEoB.png)

But I want Simulation comes at first, then adventure and so on...

How can I order calculated means in a plot?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `aes()` parameters are: `Genre, Anzhal_mods`. That is you have aesthetics in this way

```
aes(Genre,Anzhal_mods)
```

What you can do is, change that to

```
aes(reorder(Genre, -Anzhal_mods), Anzhal_mods)
```